# How do you differentiate the error with respect to weights that are far back in a neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation, calculus

OK, I am very new to creating neural networks and am working on a back propagation algorithm. Unfortunately, I am not old enough to have yet learnt calculus at school and because of my own studies don't have the time to take a full, online course.

I know how to differentiate simple functions and I know the chain rule somewhat. However, the part where it is unclear with regards to machine learning is when trying to differentiate the total error with respect to weights further towards the start of a neural network. These weights influence every other connection from then on so how do I find the rate-of-change in a situation like this.

Do I have to do the chain rule for every possible path from the total error backwards to the weight and then add them together? Is this the only way? Or am I misunderstanding the chain rule completely?

I am confident that I fully understand how to use the chain rule and backpropagate for the last set of weights and I think the second last layer. But that's generally as far back as most online tutorials go and I'm still a little foggy on how to apply that to layers further back.

Thanks so much in advance for your responses and I'm sorry if this is a stupid or badly explained question.

Comment: You enthusiasm is admirable, but I think that if you have no background in multivariate calculus and matrix analysis, then it is a bit premature to try to go into the details of backprop implementation. Your post doesn't have any math or code, so it's difficult to see whether you have understood the chainrule correctly. However, yes, you do have to apply the chainrule recursively all the way to the first layer. With respect to the weights `W_1` of the first layer, your network looks like `f_n(f_{n-1}(f_ {n-2}(....(W_1))`, and you have to apply the chainrule to that.

Comment: Take a look at http://cs231n.github.io/optimization-2/ Is the most approachable explanation I know of.

Comment: @Ash I actually asked a similar question over on reddit and got the answer I wanted. I've actually finished writing the backprop algorithm now. I just needed to look at layers as functions taking vectors instead of looking at each neuron as individual functions. I understand that it might seem premature for me to try to grasp all of calculus all at once when we are only doing linear relations at school but I've learnt enough that I fully understand end can execute backprop so I think I'm catching on reasonably quickly. Thanks for your response. Wish me luck on my journeys with ML.

Comment: Well that's great! So you do have some background in multivariate calculus now :p I still think it would be beneficial in the long term for you if you focused more on the math part than on the implementation, but what do I know anyway. Yup, good luck!

Comment: @Ash, I'm sure you know plenty. Thanks for your help.